# run batch file in npm script

Tags: batch-file, npm-scripts

Is it possible and how to run a batch script in npm command?

I have an angular project, in `package.json` file, under `scripts` section, I want to define a npm command to run batch script. I know I can run shell script with keyword `bash` e.g.

```json
"start": "cd mydir && bash ./myscript"
```

Then I can run `npm start` in my project directory, which will change directory and execute `myscript.sh` script. **What is the equivalent keyword to run batch script in npm?**

Newbie here. Sorry if this is a duplicate question; maybe I'm not search the correct terms, but I can't see to find answers to this question.

Comment: Is your intention to invoke the _npm-script_, i.e. the one which executes the batch script (`.cmd` or `.bat` file), via Windows Command Prompt  (i.e. cmd.exe)? Or will you be using another console, such as PowerShell ?

Comment: Yes, I want to execute the batch script inside cmd.exe. Say I want to type `npm blah` in terminal, and that will execute `myscript.bat` file in cmd.exe for me. How should I define `blah` now?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

To help provide context to this answer, let's say we two batch files named `say-hello.bat` and `say-hello-cmd`. Both batch files have the same simple contrived content as follows:

```
echo Hello World
```

When invoking either of the two batch files via `npm-scripts`, we expect the console to log:

> `Hello World`

**Project Directory Structure:**

Now, let's assume our project directory is structured as follows:

```
.
├── a
│   └── b
│       ├── say-hello.bat
│       └── say-hello.cmd
├── package.json
├── say-hello.bat
├── say-hello.cmd
└── ...
```

As you can see, we have:

- `say-hello.bat` and `say-hello.cmd` stored in the root of the project directory. They're at the same level as `package.json`.
- We also have `say-hello.bat` and `say-hello.cmd` stored in a sub directory of the project directory The path to these is: `a/b/`

**npm-scripts**

To be able to invoke these batch files via `npm`, the `scripts` section of `package.json` should be defined something like the following:

```json
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "bat": "say-hello.bat",
    "cmd": "say-hello.cmd",
    "bat-in-sub-dir": "cd a/b/ && say-hello.bat",
    "cmd-in-sub-dir": "cd a/b/ && say-hello.cmd"
  },
  ...
}
```

If you now `cd` to your project directory and run any of the following commands:

- `npm run bat`
- `npm run cmd`
- `npm run bat-in-sub-dir`
- `npm run cmd-in-sub-dir`

The batch file(s) will be run and you will successfully see the words `Hello World` logged to the console.

**Notes**

The notable difference between these examples above is:

- When the batch file is stored in the root of your projects directory you just provide the name of the batch file in your script. E.g.

  ```json
  "bat": "say-hello.bat"
  ```
- When the batch file is stored in a sub directory of your project directory (e.g. `a/b/`) you have to firstly `cd` to that folder, and then provide the name of the batch file to run. E.g.

  ```json
  "bat-in-sub-dir": "cd a/b/ && say-hello.bat"
  ```

Comment: Thanks Rob! I thought I need extra keyword to run the script. XD

Answer (score 1):

You can use directly

```json
"start": "mydir\\myscript.bat"
```