# Archiving reports, cypress.json file

Tags: node.js, json, npm, cypress, mochawesome

I want to store all new and previous reports in my directory.

**Current behavior**

Right now after running tests by 'npm run test' previous reports are deleted or appended (when i delete line clean reports in package.json).

**Desired behavior**

I want to give my directory path a dynamic name e.g with current date or number so previous ones stays where they are but i don't know if it is possible to do it inside cypres.json. Is there any solution workaround?

**Code**

**package.json**

"scripts": {
"clean:reports": rmdir /S /Q cypress\reports && mkdir cypress\reports && mkdircypress\reports\mochareports",

"pretest": "npm run archive-report && npm run clean:reports",

"scripts": "cypress run --browser chrome",

"combine-reports": "mochawesome-merge ./cypress/reports/chrome/mocha/*.json > cypress/reports/chrome/mochareports/report.json",

"generate-report": "marge cypress/reports/chrome/mochareports/report.json -f report -o cypress/reports/chrome/mochareports",

"posttest-chrome": "npm run combine-reports && npm run generate-report",

"test-chrome": "npm run scripts || npm run posttest-chrome"

**cypress.json**

"reporter": "cypress-multi-reporters",

"reporterOptions": {

"reporterEnabled": "mochawesome",

"mochaFile": "raports/my-test-output-.xml",

"mochawesomeReporterOptions": {

"reportDir": "cypress/reports/mocha",

"quite": true,

"overwrite": false,

"html": false,

"json": true

}
}

simillar: [ReportDir of a mochawesome reporter option in cypress.json to point to folder created at run time named after timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54117707/reportdir-of-a-mochawesome-reporter-option-in-cypress-json-to-point-to-folder-cr)

Comment: Try this method It will work 100 % https://softans.com/using-mochawesome-reporter-with-cypress/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround:
If you start the tests in some CI, then once `npm run test` command is finished you can add additional steps to do this for you, for bash it would be something like:

```
dirName="$(date +"%d-%m-%Y-%H:%M:%S")"
mkdir $dirName
mv cypress/screenshots/*.json $dirName
```

More details regarding the `dirName` [here](https://ostechnix.com/how-to-create-directories-named-with-current-date-time-month-year/).

Comment: I would like to make entire process automatic, I hope there is something to do in package.json e.g in posttest

Comment: Sure thing: just add "posttest": "./posttest.sh" to your package.json, and add these commands in the posttest.sh file next to package.json. You'll probably need to play around with correct paths.

Comment: I am getting  ./posttest.sh

'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

operable program or batch file.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! errno 1

npm ERR! cypress-tests@1.0.0 posttest: `./posttest.sh`

npm ERR! Exit status 1

npm ERR!

npm ERR! Failed at the cypress-tests@1.0.0 posttest script.

npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging
 output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

Comment: If you use windows then please adjust the commands as these ones are linux specific, you can start from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50243229/run-batch-file-in-npm-script

Comment: Thanks it works! I have added "save-reports": "@powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command ./posttest.ps1" to Scripts in package.json and in posttest.ps1 commands like copy-item, rename-item